# Is there a way to use bigger font for Facebook plugin Recommendation?

Tags: css, facebook, plugins

For Facebook recommendation plugin,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/recommendations/

I use it in my site and I found it uses font size 11px, which is too small for me.

I thought I could add a div around the code to use bigger font like this

```
<div style="font-size: 15px !important;">
... recommendation box
</div>
```

but it does not work. Is there any method to achieve so?

Comment: Is this just for you? Then you can put a new style for the plugin itself in your user stylesheet.

Comment: Take a look on this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: @luck the recommendation is in html5, not using iframe